# Android accessibility for edittext with prefiled text

Tags: android, accessibility

I have a field for a code which always starts with the same four letters, so those are prefilled. The problem is, because they are prefilled, the hint of the edittext isn't being read by TalkBack, they just hear four numbers.

Is it possible to share the hint and the prefilled numbers ?

Thanks

Comment: try using textinputlayout

Comment: `TextInputLayout` won't solve this problem

Comment: You can use a TextView and a EditText.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way you can show text and hint inside an `EditText` at the same instance. 
You can use `AutoCompleteTextView`

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
         AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                 findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
         textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now, when the user will tap your `textView`(autoComplete), then as there is some String of prefilled, so he'll get the hits according to your **List**

Answer (score 0):

You can try labelFor to put the description in the textview, if you want you can hide it using visibility="gone". TalkBack will detect the labelFor attribute and will not depend on hint of EditText.

```
<TextView
android:labelFor="@+id/edittext"
android:text="Text About EditText Below" />
<EditText android:id="@+id/edittext"/>
```